# How to make a web scraper / crawler / robot "friendly"?

Tags: web-scraping, web-crawler, robots.txt

By "friendly", I mean considerations outside of `robots.txt`[[1](http://www.robotstxt.org),[2]](https://developers.google.com/search/reference/robots_txt) and [`<meta>` tag](http://www.robotstxt.org/meta.html):

- **respectful of certain metrics** (e.g., spare bandwidth by making periodic scrapes, or avoid huge number of simultaneous or repeated requests)
- **transparency** and **accountability** (i.e., making it easy for someone to look up information about its origin and purpose, such as [this](http://www.robotstxt.org/db/arks.html). Is this only possible via providing a unique [`User-Agent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent) HTTP header for the project?)
- **What else should be included in this list?**